# can we make multiple rows as comma seperated in SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, string-aggregation

can we make multiple rows as comma seperated in SQL Query?

query should return something like:

```
1, "john,mike,petra"
2, "bob,carl,sandra,peter,
etc
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What does your data look like? What kind of queries have you attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the all the columns to be comma separated and concatenated as a single string for each row?
If yes, you can use this code.

```
select Name+','+Phone_NO+','+Address from <table_name>
```

Result will be looked like the following lines:

1. Bob,6589235,Anderson Street
2. Jake,8547868,Jefferson Street

If your column is not varchar type then you have to cast the columns.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be acomplished via Management Studio [image]